# Bottom Toolbar looks like moving when switching from activity to activity

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, toolbar, activity-transition

I am trying to have a bottom `Toolbar`. In 3 activities having the below same code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarmenucontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/home"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/news"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="AddImage"
        android:src="@drawable/upload"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/search"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/useraccount"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/user"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But every time I switch from activity to another it show like its moving. Is there a better way to have a bottom `Toolbar`?

Comment: you can use fragments

Comment: @NileshRathod most application use fragments ? isnt there a standward way from bottom toolbar ?

Comment: with activity i don't think that work as per your requirement

Comment: `it show like its moving` - what does that mean? Can you post a gif?

Comment: @azizbekian It doenst show like its fix, i dont know how to post as gif asthe issue on my phone